# Find the unique distribution of a random variable knowing the moments of the random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This problem comes from Allan Gut's 'An Intermediate Course in Probability', but I cannot solve the problem.

The random variable $X$ has the property that $$EX^{n}=\frac{2^{n}}{n+1}, \quad n = 1,2, ...$$

Find some (in fact, the unique) distribution of X having these moments.

I know that the moment-generating function (MGF) can be expressed as $$\psi_{X}(t)= E\, e^{tX} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}EX^{k}.$$

I tried to use this expression to find an expression of the MGF that I can use to identify the distribution:

$$\psi_{X}(t) = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}\frac{2^{k}}{k+1} = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(2t)^{k}}{k!(k+1)}$$
$$ = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(2t)^{k+1}}{2t(k+1)!} = 1 + \frac{1}{2t}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(2t)^{k}}{k!} = 1+\frac{1}{2t}e^{2t}$$

But this is not an MGF I recognize, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks! That makes sense, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: let $Y=X/2$; then $\mathbb E\left[Y^n\right]=1/(n+1)$ which is the integral of $y\mapsto y^n$ over an interval I let you find.

Answer (score 4):

You had a mistake in your calculation of the moment generating function, when reindexing the sum. In fact,
$$
1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2t)^{k+1}}{2t(k+1)!}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(2t)^{k}}{2tk!}=1+\frac{e^{2t}-2t-1}{2t},
$$
which is different what you wrote (you had the sum starting at $0$ and not at $2$). Simplifying this expression yields
$$
\mathbb Ee^{tX}=\frac{e^{2t}-1}{2t},
$$
which you may recognize as the moment generating function of the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,2]$.